# useState object returning different values from different callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a small React Native app and I'm seeing some very odd behavior with a `useState` object. Below is a trimmed version of the code. `WeightSelector` is a custom component that sets the the `totalWeight` value. I can see the correct value reflected in the `<Text>` object once the value is set, as well as through other callbacks.

Now, I am observing the following behavior

- When the Log button is pressed, `handleSwipeRelease` prints the correct `weight` value (the one that is displayed).
- When the SwipeableButton returns, `handleSwipeRelease` always shows `weight` to be zero.
- If I try accessing `totalWeight` from `handleSwipeRelease` directly, I still get zero.

```
const DetailScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const [totalWeight, setTotalWeight] = useState(0);

  const handleSwipeRelease = (val, weight) => {
    console.log("Logging val: " + val + " w " + weight);
    ...
  }

  ...

  return (
    <>
    <WeightSelector
        onSelectWeight={(weightValue) => setTotalWeight(weightValue)}
    />

    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.weightText}>{totalWeight} lbs      X </Text>
      <SwipeableButton onSwipeRelease={(val) => handleSwipeRelease(val, totalWeight)} />
    </View>

    <Button title="Log" onPress={() => handleSwipeRelease(7, totalWeight)} />
    ...
    </>
  );
};
```

`SwipeableButton` is a relatively involved animated component, but it essentially takes the callback in as so

```
const SwipeableButton = ({ onSwipeRelease }) => {
```

and uses it within the `onPanResponderRelease` of a `PanResponder`

I've tried accessing `totalWeight` from `handleSwipeRelease` directly, I still get zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setTotalWeight` to update the state, React doesn't immediately update the `totalWeight` variable. Instead, it **schedules an update, and the actual state change may not be reflected immediately** (only use effect can get instant updates from state).

In your case, when you call `handleSwipeRelease(7, totalWeight)`, the `totalWeight` might not have been updated yet, leading to the issue.

To ensure that you're using the most up-to-date state in your `handleSwipeRelease` function, you can use the functional form of `setTotalWeight`:

```
const DetailScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const [totalWeight, setTotalWeight] = useState(0);

  const handleSwipeRelease = (val) => {
    setTotalWeight((prevTotalWeight) => {
      console.log("Logging val: " + val + " w " + prevTotalWeight);
      // Use prevTotalWeight in your logic if needed
      // ...
      return prevTotalWeight;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <WeightSelector
        onSelectWeight={(weightValue) => setTotalWeight(weightValue)}
      />

      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.weightText}>{totalWeight} lbs      X </Text>
        <SwipeableButton onSwipeRelease={() => handleSwipeRelease(totalWeight)} />
      </View>

      <Button title="Log" onPress={() => handleSwipeRelease(7)} />
      {/* ... */}
    </>
  );
};
```

By using the functional form of `setTotalWeight`, you ensure that you're using the most up-to-date state. This is especially important when you are updating the state based on its previous value. The `prevTotalWeight` argument inside the callback represents the current state at the time the state update is scheduled.

if you want the console log to show the correct logs when the state changes then put the log within a use effect like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(stateValue);
},[stateVlue]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. This works, although I still don't understand why
- i can see totalWeight reflected correctly in the UI
- and the Button click records the correct value, whereas the swipe button doesn't

Comment: It is the way use state works under the hood. That's why we need to use the functional form to get the current state instead of using the current state value. This can be observed when you have a button that updates state and you console log the same state in the same function that updates it. it will look like the value is not updated but it actually is in the dom

Comment: rule of thumb if you are updating state and using a previous state at all, make sure to use the functional form to update state such as setState((prev)=>{return {...prev, newValue:'test'}})

Comment: if you want the console log to show the correct logs when the state changes then put the log within a use effect like this: useEffect(()=>{console.log(stateValue);},[stateVlue]);